# Returning the Inserted Id as Out parameter in postgres

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

All,I am new to PostgreSQL and was playing around with that and .Net using NpgSql plugin.My intention is to capture the inserted id from the database and use that in the .Net 4.5 application

I created the PostgreSQL function.It compiles fine,but cannot get that to work in Pg Admin.When I try to call the function from Pg Admin, I see the column id doesnt exist error

My Postgres function is as follows

```
create or replace function appuser_address_create(address1 varchar(200),  address2 varchar(200), zip varchar(15),district varchar(50),state varchar(100),out address_id int) 
returns integer
as
$$
begin
   insert  into address(address1,address2,postalcode,district,state)
   values (address1,address2,zip,district,state)
   returning id into address_id;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

-- This gives me error,though the function compiles
select * from  appuser_address_create('123 Mainstreet','Jacksonville','32218','District4','Florida')
```

Comment: ... and the *exact error message text* is...?

Comment: Column id doesn't exist

Comment: So, presumably there is no column `id` in the `address` table. Perhaps you should show output of `\d address` (i.e. show the table definition of table `address`)

Comment: Thanks Craig.I was under the impression that returning id is a built in postgres way to get the inserted id in the current session(like scope_identity() in T-Sql).My primary key column name in the address table was addressid .Changing id to addressid fixed the issue

Comment: Ah, gotcha. There was a discussion about supporting a `RETURNING PRIMARY KEY` feature, but it turns out to be rather more complicated than you might think, and wasn't carried forward.